# Is there a code to move the nav bar below a header graphic?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to move the navigation bar below my header image.  When I do move it below the image it gives major white space or it disappears behind the header image. I have tried several different CSS tricks from various sources to try get what I want. As I said it just either moves to the bottom or stays at the top or disappears behind the header image.

```css
    body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: #f2f6e9;
    }

    /*--- navigation bar ---*/

    .navbar {
 background: #6ab446;
    }

    .nav-link,
    .navbar-brand {
    color: #fff;
 cursor: pointer;
    }

    .nav-link {
   margin-right: 1em !important;
    }

    .nav-link:hover {
 color: #000;
    }

    .navbar-collapse {
 justify-content: flex-end;
    }


    /*--- header ---*/

    .header {
   background-image: url('images/logo2w5.png');
 background-size: contain;
 background-position: top center;
 position: relative;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark" type="button" data toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navigation">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>

    <header class="page-header header container-fluid">

    </header>
```

The code above is just putting the navigation bar on top of the header image.

Comment: Can you change de HTML code?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the issue. Where's the header image? Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue you are having with the code you have supplied. https://jsfiddle.net/WizardCoder/gs9xzfch/. In that jsfiddle I have moved the nav below the header and added a height to the header so the background image shows. There must be some other CSS at play that is causing your issue.

Comment: I noticed you were using relative links for the boostrap CSS and JS. Adding those still doesn't cause the issue you are experiencing. https://jsfiddle.net/WizardCoder/gs9xzfch/

Comment: I have updated the code with the changes. The nav bar is still going to the bottom of the page. I will keep trying different variations.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this sample helps

```css
body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
background: #f2f6e9;
}

/*--- navigation bar ---*/

.navbar {
background: #6ab446;
}

.nav-link,
.navbar-brand {
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-link {
  margin-right: 1em !important;
}

.nav-link:hover {
color: #000;
}

.navbar-collapse {
justify-content: flex-end;
}


/*--- header ---*/

.header {
background-image: url('images/logo2w5.png');
background-size: contain;
background-position: top center;
position: relative;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding: 0 !important;
margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
<header class="page-header header container-fluid">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500x400" alt="img" width="100%" />
</header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark" type="button" data toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navigation">
<ul class="navbar-nav">
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>


</body>
</html>
```